# How can I set 50 column values of excel sheet dynamically using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

Actually, I'm trying to Write "Test" string Value from 1st column to 50th column( i.e A column to AZ column).

I can Write upto 26th Column (i.e Z column), below is my code:-

```
import pandas as pd

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("Sharath.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', header=True, index=False)
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

merge_format = workbook.add_format({
            'bold': True,
            'text_wrap': True,
            'border': 2,
            'align': 'center',
            'valign': 'vcenter'})

for i in range(0, 26):
    columnmerge = chr(ord('A') + i) + '{}:' + chr(ord('A') + i) + '{}'
    worksheet.set_column(chr(ord('A') + i) + ':' + chr(ord('A') + i), 20)
    worksheet.merge_range(columnmerge.format(2, 4), "Test1", merge_format)


workbook.close()
print("Excel file is closed")

writer.save()
print("Excel file is saved")
print("Report generation completed")
```

If I tried for 27th Column(i.e AA column) I'm getting below error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\test2.py", line 18, in <module>
    worksheet.set_column(chr(ord('A') + i) + ':' + chr(ord('A') + i), 20)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py", line 120, in column_wrapper
    _, col_1 = xl_cell_to_rowcol(cell_1)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\utility.py", line 121, in xl_cell_to_rowcol
    col_str = match.group(2)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Can any one help me to write my string upto 50-100 columns dynamically.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All XlsxWriter methods take `(row, col)` values as well as `A1` style ranges. When trying to set ranges programatically it is always best to avoid trying to construct `A1` ranges and let the library do it for you based on zero-base row-column numbers.

For example here is how you could restructure your program to use arbitrary indices:

```py
import pandas as pd

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Sharath.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', header=True, index=False)

workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

merge_format = workbook.add_format({
            'bold': True,
            'text_wrap': True,
            'border': 2,
            'align': 'center',
            'valign': 'vcenter'})

first_col = 0
last_col = 100

worksheet.set_column(first_col, last_col, 20)

for col in range(last_col + 1):
    worksheet.merge_range(1, col, 3, col, 'Test1', merge_format)

writer.save()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Set the column width and merge a range using the column number:

```
worksheet.set_column(i, i, 20)
worksheet.merge_range(2, i, 4, i, "Test1", merge_format)
```

Comment: No, It's not working, Have you executed my code?

Comment: @kgsharathkumar See my edit.

Comment: Its works for me! Thank you and I have given up vote for this! @Michael